# What's the trick to display a text from MySql/PHP back to its original HTML layout?

Tags: php, mysql

It still keeps the original text layout (I mean the spacing, offsets, new line, paragraphs) while the text fragment is stored in MySql ('text' type) field - I can tell when I peer into it in my DB browser (Adminer:) 
but it gets lost when I output it from the DB: it becomes a single line string of my text characters. How can one restore it its original layout? 
I've tried to reshape the text fragment using the PHP nl2br() function with some success: 
it brought back the newline breaks, but the text words positioning is not kept, everything 
shifts to the left. 
Thanks in advance for a good idea.

Comment: Please show some example code

Answer (score 3):

If you've got multiple spaces and things like that. e.g. for code. Then trying using the pre tag.

http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/pre

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/pre

Comment: Just the same as Stack Overflow does it. :D

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools. Their junk doesn't need more pagerank boosting as is.

Comment: Can you suggest a better reference for it?

Comment: But - I mean - the pre tag has to be preserved in the DB record... will it not be escaped?   I think I have mysql_real_escape and stripslahes functions in the script, wile it work, you think?

Comment: I wouldn't put the pre tag in the database, just wrap it around the output. i.e. `echo '<pre>'.$output.'</pre>`

Comment: It's great - I'm almost there! I have tested out some and it looks promising. Thank you very much, Jacob                             Happy Valentine!

Answer (score 0):

The html_entity_decode() function converts HTML entities to characters.

The syntax is:

```
html_entity_decode(string, [quotestyle], [character-set]);
```

You can refer [example2](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_html_entity_decode.asp).